# Secure root-server with SSL on own domain

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

I'm asking the question this way, to ensure I'm not asking an x-y-question and I understand way too less to ask an elaborate question.

I rented a root-server that hosts some apps that I want to reach over the internet. For example my postgreSQL DB is exposed on port 1234 and the domain name, provided by the server provider is `rootserver5678.provider.com`. I am able to navigate to `rootserver5678.provider.com:1234` and access the exposed webapp. Furthermore I have a domain registered that is `mydomain.de` and I can register subdomains such as `database.mydomain.de`. I want the subdomain to point to my webapp and the connection to be secured, so that calls to `database.mydomain.de` are forced to be https. What is the correct way to do that?

Is it okay to do domain forwarding from `database.mydomain.de` to `rootserver5678.provider.com:1234` or do I need to change the DNS entries of my subdomain to use the DNS from my server provider? Do I install SSL certificates for the new subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> postgreSQL DB is exposed on port 1234 and the domain name, provided
>   by the server provider is `rootserver5678.provider.com`. I am able to
>   navigate to `rootserver5678.provider.com:1234` and access the exposed
>   webapp.

PostgresSQL cannot be listing on the same port as a http server. I assume you are running a web server on ports 80 and 443, which connects to Postgres on localhost.

> domain forwarding from `database.mydomain.de` to `rootserver5678.provider.com:1234`

First, DNS does not work this way, it only resolves the name, not the port. Second, you mention the PostgreSQL port as if it were public access over the Internet.  Exposing PostgreSQL protocol is poor security. It exposes the database to denial of service attacks, even if the connection is secured with TLS.

What you can do is edit the DNS of `database.mydomain.de` to be a CNAME to `rootserver5678.provider.com`, or create AAAA and A records with its static IP addresses. Issue a certificate for `database.mydomain.de` and configure the web server for https per its documentation.